# Python argparse unexpected behavior when passing "``" to the argument string in pysaprk cluster mode

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, argparse

I am trying to pass a string in my pyspark code and it works fine but when i pass the following string to escape reserved keyword

```
`date` or any value passed in ``
```

in  it behaves unexpectedly.

below is the test code i am using:

```
import argparse

def getArgParser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Write Hive table to Mongo/Kafka')
    parser.add_argument("--query", action="store",
                        help= "query", type=str)
              
    return parser



def main(job_parameters: dict):

    print(job_parameters.get('query', None))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = getArgParser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(vars(args))
```

Now the command i using
when i run

```
> spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  test.py  --query
> 'select `id`,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(`date` ,"MM/dd/yyyy"),
> "yyyy-MM-dd") as dt from db.table '
```

I get

> 'select , from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(Fri May  6 15:05:30 UTC 2022
> ,"MM/dd/yyyy"), "yyyy-MM-dd") from db.table '

that is in place of date i get todays date and the value in `` are missing.

but when the same code is ran into client mode the result is as expected.

```
> spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  test.py  --query
> 'select `id`,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(`date` ,"MM/dd/yyyy"),
> "yyyy-MM-dd") as dt from db.table '
```

PS: My orignal code is pyspark this python code is for testing purpose.
Can anyone help here to find the cause of the issue ?

Comment: When debugging I suggest including a `print(args)` (and may be even `print(sys.argv)`) to check whether the parser is doing what you expect.  It that's correct, then the problem isn't in the parsing, but in the following application.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the response , i checked both the print statement and the result is still unexpected behaviour as above